# Autoclick 3 times over iframe on page load

Tags: javascript

I am using this iframe:

```
<iframe id="myframe1" src="https://777sportba.com/3c27348e623319abb826edabaeba4aee-live.html"></iframe>
```

I need a javascript code so when page load to trigger autoclick over the iframe 3 times. Or other option when I click once over the iframe to simulate as it is clicked 3 times. Is one of the option possible to be done?

Answer (score 0):

```js
const clicked = () => {
  console.log("clicked")
}

const autoClick = async () => {
  const innerButton = await document.querySelector('#myframe1');
  let click = new MouseEvent('click', {
      view: window,
      bubbles: true,
      cancelable: true
   });
  
   for(let i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
     innerButton.dispatchEvent(click);
   }
}

autoClick();
```

```html
<iframe id="myframe1" src="" onclick="clicked()"></iframe>
```

Comment: Sir, I try this script but not working for my iframe. This is the error - Cannot read property 'dispatchEvent' of null at autoClick

Comment: I updated my answer; try it with async/await syntax. Can you also provide your entire html?

Comment: I updated in my question the entire iframe that i need 3 autoclicks on page load or when i click on it

Comment: check the codepen again; it's definitely being clicked though the source doesn't seem to point to anything. Are you trying to click a specific element within iframe? What is supposed to happen when it gets clicked?

Comment: async/await is not needed in order to query the DOM

Comment: because this iframe player need to be clicked 4 times on playbutton for mobile devices to start playing and 2 times on computers . so i want on page load to be autoclicked 3 times so there will be no need of manual multiple clicks

Comment: is the play button inside the iframe? If so, you need to use the id of the play button, not the id of the iframe.

Comment: yes this is the class of the playbutton:  .vjs-big-play-button  but no matter if i click the playbutton or anywhere else on the iframe is the same. need for 4 clicks no matter where i click on the iframe - the whole frame represent playbutton

Comment: is the source you provided correct? it doesn't render a page for me; I could see what's going on if I had access to that page.

Comment: yes this is the correct source: https://777sportba.com/3c27348e623319abb826edabaeba4aee-live.html but i see you mistake and change codepen html incorrectly to <iframe id="myframe1" src="https://codepen.io/PavlosKaralis/pen/qBbPdge?editors=1111" onclick="clicked()"></iframe>

Comment: I did that after I couldn't get the source to work; I also noticed your source is an html file, not a website, so that's why I can't get it to work (I don't have the file).